# Creating sub-part within memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir

This question had been already asked by someone who was using `titlesec`.

My question is, is it possible to create an intermediate section level between Part and Chapter within the `memoir` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but why? How would it be used? What would it look like?

`memoir` has both `\book` and `\part` divisions and you could consider `\part` to be a kind of sub-book. I suggest you use `\book` where you now use `\part` and use `\part` as your sub-part. You would need to change the printed names like

```
\renewcommand{\bookname}{Part}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Sub-Part}
```

and perhaps some other things as well. See section  **Book and part headings** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

If you wanted to create a sub-part from scratch then again read that section in the manual to get an idea of what it might involve, then read the relevant code passages in `memoir.cls`.

Another complication is that each LaTeX sectional division has an associated level number which is used to control whether the title appears in the ToC and whether the division is numbered. In `memoir` these are `-2,`-1,`and`0`for`\book`,`\part`and`\chapter`respectively. If you wanted to insert a sup-part into this list then you would also have to reduce the levels for`\part`and`\book`.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I'm writing my thesis and I've got two big parts in it but each one is divided into sub-parts that contain chapters.

Answer (score 1):

"The  memoir  class  lets  you  divide  a  document  up  into  eight  levels  of  named  divisions.They range from book, part through chapter and down to sub-paragraph. A particular sec-tional division is specified by one of the commands\book,\part,\chapter,\section,\subsection, which is probably as deep as you want to go. If you really need finer divi-sions, they are\subsubsection,\paragraphand lastly\subparagraph. The sectionalcommands, except for\bookand\part, have the same form, so rather than describingeach one in turn I will use\sectionas model for all but the two exceptions." quote the page 76 Memoir User [Guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, As I should have said and phrased better, I'm writing my PhD and have two big parts divided into sub-parts and themselves being divided into chapters.